# TouchBar keeps freezing

Tags: mac, performance, touch-bar

The TouchBar in my new MacBookPro 2017 keeps freezing every time I use it to adjust the brightness of the screen. In order to circumvent this, I need to use the "Force Quit" command,  but is becoming really annoying.

Has this happened to anyone before? How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known issue. The touch bar is quite finicky. Try these scripts in the terminal:

Kill touch bar - `pkill "Touch Bar agent"`

Refresh control strip - `killall ControlStrip`

Additionally, if the scripts didn't solve your issue and you are still under the 90 days of free Apple Care, I'd recommend taking it in. There are a number of things that could be wrong with it and it's really hard to diagnose + solve without a physical examination from an expert.